# How to evaluate this path integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image: problem]

So I know that the integral is $$\int_1^e f(x(t), y(t), z(t))(||c'(t)||) \:dt$$

I set this to$$\int_1^e\frac{1}{t^3}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(ln10*t)^2}+1}\; dt$$

I found this too hard to integrate by hand, so I used a calculator and I got the wrong answer. The answer should be

[image]

Could someone tell me what I did wrong? Thank you!

Comment: In that book, does $\log (*)$ mean $\log_{10} (*)$ or $\log (*)=\ln(*)$?

Comment: Hmm... this book usually uses $log(*) = log_{10}(*)$ but I suppose in this case it must be ln. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\log (*)$ means $\log_e (*)$ or $\ln (*)$ then we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbf{c}}{f(x,y,z)ds}&=\int_{1}^{e}f(x(t),y(t),z(t))(||c′(t)||)dt\\
&=\int_{1}^{e}{\frac{1}{t^3}\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+1}\;dt}\\
&=\int_{1}^e{t^{-3}\sqrt{t^{-2}+1}\,dt}\\
&=\left.-\frac{1}{3}\left(t^{-2}+1\right)^{3/2}\right|_1^e\\
&=-\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{e^2}\right)^{3/2}+\frac{1}{3}(2^{3/2})
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $u = \dfrac{1}{(t^2\ln^2 10)}$